# 2 man project - java+database programmers

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, project-management

My friend and I are entering our final year at the university (M.Sc.) in 2 months and as such we have to start thinking about our dissertation (as we decided to write one together). After giving it some thought we came up with a topic which would involve both a lot of thinking and implementing, as we really wanted to do something practical that we could actually show in our portfolios - we will be designing and implementing a large system for didactics support for our university. The plan looked great on paper I'm a java guy (Java EE), so I'd be in charge of the web stuff, the "views", server logic etc., and he's into databases (Oracle/MySQL), and well this system will be really all about the databases.

The problem is now that I think about it I don't really see how would the teamwork look like, I mean I did a few medium size Java EE projects, I've been working for a month-two at a small comapny, but I never had a database programmer on my team, in most cases I did everything by myself with JPA/Hibernate (I didn't really need to write the databases I just used the appropriate annotations etc.). So basically my question is how do people divide work when you have someone who's good at writing the presentation layer and the server side logic and someone who's really really good at databases? Or maybe we went in a completely wrong direction and such combinations aren't necessary/possible?

@Edit: ok my bad, I thought "dissertation" is also when you're doing a Master degree (which I'm doing now). Whether this is a boring and/or well suited topic for an M.Sc. thesis let me just say that I did put a lot of thought and consideration before choosing it and I'm happy with my choice ;) (sorry for the smiley, I know some people find them juvenile). Oh also I guess I didn't really mention this (as I didn't think it's all that important) - the system itself is only a part of the thesis, the main part is to actually come up with a way to plan/support the didactic process (creating the classes scheduel etc.) which apparently isn't all that simple as my university, or at least my faculty, is struggling with it every single semester ;)

Comment: Hey I'd run this by a supervisor first, as a masters dissertation / thesis this doesn't sound particularly 'researchy'. Sounds like a standard implementation of a system. A thesis should never focus on simple tasks that others can do. It's mean to 'contribute' to the field in general. MSc is not the same as undergrad.

Comment: Well actually it was a topic suggested by one of our professors and we just tweaked it a bit. It won't be really researchy as you said, but there will be a lot of thinking involved as our prof told us. We really couldn't come up with anything on our own (guess we're very uncreative) and all the proposed topics sounded cliche (image recognition for example is very interesting but lets be honest, we wouldn't discover anything grand), so we decided to take the cliche that can be actually useful.

Comment: JEE is very, very boring.  Do something _fun_!

Comment: Just like 95% of the topics our teachers suggested us and the other 5% was already taken before we could even ask bout them ;) Like one of my friends said "don't put too much effort in your M.Sc. unless you want to continue with your studies, as there's a 99,(9)% chance that someone already wrote a way better Ph.D. disseration on the very same subject".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i myself am a database bigot.

I believe, on any large project, you should always start with a strong database design.  Work through this design carefully, test it, examine it, perform thought experiments on it, finally create it, and populate it with some sample data.  Learn from each of these steps.  Decide where the risks are from your data population efforts: where was this hard, what data problems did you create?  begin constraining the database to prevent issues.

Now, when the data model is maturing, begin your GUI work.  It is ok to think through the main use cases and general style of the UI ahead of time, but avoid coding data access of any kind until the database is maturing.

While you complete the UI, the database guy(s) can work on report SQL, triggered business logic, complicated constraints, security, backup and migration strategies etc.

have fun. :)

Comment: Well now this is a great answer guess we'll do just that, thanks! Truthfully I didn't expect to get a good answer as I thought my question was  little bit silly, but I guess you can ask anything here and get a satisfying answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Object bigots would argue that same for an object model.  What if you find out that NoSQL is a better solution for you?    Your Oracle efforts might be wasted.

Comment: well actually we (and by "we" I mean "I") are also considering using NoSQL here since it's a new technology and researching it as part of our thesis would be kinda fun and exciting. But as I said I'm not alone and I have to also take into account what my teammate wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

"Dissertation" means doctorate.  "Thesis" means Master degree.  Which one are you doing?

When you say you used JPA/Hiberate, I'll assume that it was a clean sheet design where a database didn't exist when you started.  You came up with an object model that was a faithful representation of your problem, generated the schema from it, and off you went.

If that's the case for this project, there's no reason why you can't do it again.

The one reason for having an Oracle expert would be if you found that the DDL/DML generated by Hibernate wasn't adequate for some reason.  If you need additional indexes or denormalization, perhaps a real relational database expert can help you.

Comment: About the disseration part - geuss it's my bad, as you can probably tell English isn't my native language and I always thought that dissertation can also mean a master degree (which we will be hopefully getting next year).

Actually this project is supposed to heavily rely on databases so a good design is key (it is supposed to support a university with ~30k students and X teachers/scholars), but yeah the DB doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Nope - dissertations have a uniqueness constraint; theses do not.  Your answer hinges on whether or not you think you'll have a good object model and if Hibernate's generated DDL/DML/DQL will be adequate.